# Does the Stieltjes integral $\int _1 ^2 x^2 \, d(\sqrt{x-1})$ exists? if it exists, find its value.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Does the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int _1 ^2 x^2 \, d(\sqrt{x-1})$ exists? if it exists, find its value.

$f(x)=x^2$ is continuous in $[1,2]$ y $\alpha(x) = \sqrt{x-1}$ is of bounded variation. So, the integral exists.

To compute its value, I can not use formula $\int _a ^b f(x) \, d(\alpha{(x)}) = \int _a ^b f(x) \, \alpha{(x)}' \, dx$ because $\alpha'$ does not exist at $x = 1$. How can I compute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I(a)=\int _a ^2 x^2 \, d(\sqrt{x-1})\qquad a>1$$
$t=\sqrt{x-1} \quad\to\quad x=t^2+1$
$$I(a)=\int _{(\sqrt{a-1})} ^{(\sqrt{2-1})} (t^2+1)^2 \, dt =\int _{(\sqrt{a-1})} ^1 (t^2+1)^2 \, dt  = \left[\frac{t^5}{5}+2\frac{t^3}{3}+t\right]_{t=\sqrt{a-1}}^{t=1} $$
$$I(a)=\frac{1}{5}+2\frac{1}{3}+1-\frac{(a-1)^{5/2}}{5}-2\frac{(a-1)^{3/2}}{3}-(a-1)^{1/2}$$
$$\lim\limits_{a\to 1} \left(I(a)\right)=\frac{28}{15}$$
$$\int _1 ^2 x^2 \, d(\sqrt{x-1})=\frac{28}{15}$$